# How to scroll to a Ref within a modal scree in react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, js-scrollto

I currently have multiple components within a bootstrap modal. My goal is to be able to do a window.scroll to a given component following a user action. Basically, this is what I have tried:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.myref = React.createRef();   

  }
  
  // function that I have been trying to invoke. 
  scrollToRef = () => {
    window.scrollTo({top: this.myref.current.offsetTop, behavior: "smooth"})
  }

  render () {
     return (
     <Modal>
         <ComponentOne/>
         <ComponentTwo/>
         <ComponentThree ref={this.myref}/>
     </Modal> 
     )

  }

}
```

All of my components are class components. I even tried wrapping ComponentThree in a div tag if that made a difference, but no luck. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`window.scrollTo` would pertain to the `window` object, therefore will attempt to scroll the `window`, not the `<Modal>` component. For this, you can have another `ref` attached to the `<Modal>`, and that is the element you would use `scrollTo` on. Since `<ComponentThree>` is already a direct child of `<Modal>`, you can continue using the `offsetTop` property but take note:

> `offsetTop` is the number of pixels from the top of the closest
> **relatively positioned** parent element

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am knew to frontend dev, so this might sound like a basic question. How do I do scrollTo off of modal exactly? This is what I tried: Created another ref, attached it to modal, and then tried to do scrollTo using that ref. That is not working for me.

Comment: Does it have a scrollbar visible? If not you can use `max-height` & `overflow` CSS properties. Basically you do the same thing in using `scrollTo` like you did with the `window`, except this time you do it on the modal element with **overflowing content (therefore has a scrollbar)**. If you wish to retain the scrolling using the `window` object, the distance to scroll has to be relative to the `window` not to the modal. In a standard implementation setting, the overflowing content probably does not belong to the main modal container immediately but to the modal inner content container.